# NSControl does not work on different Mac

Tags: interface-builder, nswindow, nscombobox, nscontrol, nscolorwell

I encountered a very strange problem which I can't solve by myself. I have several UI elements embedded in a `NSWindow` running as `NSBorderlessWindowMask`. There are 2 `NSSlider`, 3 `NSButton`, a `NSComboBox` and a `NSColorWell`.

The application builds for target 10.7 and has sandboxing enabled.

On my development machine every element works as intended. The `NSComboBox` has a working `DataSource` and `Delegate`. The `NSColorWell` does work too. When I click into the `NSComboBox`, I can type a text into it. And the `NSColorWell` opens a color selection.

The moment I hand my app to my beta-tester, the `NSComboBox` and the `NSColorWell` can't be edited. This means, that I can add elements to the `DataSource` of the `NSComboBox` (via an import) and they may be selected in the dropdown menu, but I can't click into the `NSComboBoxCell` and write a text. Also no color selection opens when I click the `NSColorWell`.

I have no clue at all what could cause this behavior. Every element is hooked up correctly and I run the same binary as my beta-tester. The systems both run Mountain Lion in its latest version. I tried creating a `NSButton` for the beta-tester which runs following methods on the `NSComboBox`:

```
[self.nameCB reloadData];
[self.nameCB setEnabled:YES];
[self.nameCB setEditable:YES];
[self.nameCB setNeedsDisplay:YES];
[self.nameCB setFrame:self.nameCB.frame];
[self.nameCB becomeFirstResponder];
[self.nameCB setSelectable:YES];
```

None helped. I have no clue how to "debug" this behavior. Do you have any suggestions?

---

**Edit:** I was able to break it down a bit. When I remove the line

```
[self.window setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

It works. But I want to get a nice look from removing the titlebar, so it only helps a bit.

Comment: same issue.. any help?

Comment: Didn't my accepted solution work for you?

Comment: my project is in MRR,.. this wont working

Comment: MRR? I know this term as “Monthly Recurring Revenue” and cannot connect the dots. Could you specify?

Comment: Whola.. What i mean is Manual Reference Counting

Comment: Why won’t subclassing NSWindow work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142738/discussion-between-thomas-johannesmeyer-and-saranjith).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already edited into my question I found out that this problem is caused by the `NSBorderlessWindowMask` style on my main `NSWindow`. I found no other way around it than subclassing `NSWindow`.

I used [this example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) as a guide. It also works if you just extract the `CustomWindow` class from the project and add it to your project. Then just set the class of your window in IB to the `CustomWindow`

I still don't know what caused this problem. If anybody has an idea feel free to leave another answer below please.